# Get passing variable by name error

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native, and I can successfully run navigate example (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html) locally:

But I don't understand, why this code:

```
const { navigation } = this.props;
const itemId = navigation.getParam('name', 'NO-ID');
```

can succefully get the value of variable 'name', but if I modified it to:

```
//const { navigation } = this.props;
const itemId = this.props.getParam('name', 'NO-ID');
```

Android emulator would complain:

```
undefined is not a function (evaluating  const itemId = this.props.getParam('name', 'NO-ID') )
```

?

Since { navigation } would be same as this.props ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have confused with es6 destructuring.

```
const { navigation } = this.props;
```

is equal to

```
const navigation = this.props.navigation;
```

It is just a syntactic sugar. 
In your case you should correct your code like below:

```
const itemId = this.props.navigation.getParam('name', 'NO-ID')
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know 'es6 destructuring', will look into it.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot this.props.NAVIGATION :)

```
// const { navigation } = this.props;
const itemId = this.props.navigation.getParam('name', 'NO-ID');
```